# How does nested list comprehension work in Python?

Tags: python-3.x

I have to write a list comprehension for making a list with alphabets from a list of strings without repeating the alphabets.
for example:

```
words = ['cat', 'dog', 'rabbit']
```

should return

```
['c', 'a', 't', 'd', 'o', 'g', 'r', 'b', 'i']
```

I first used  nested for loops with if like this:

```
words = ['cat', 'dog', 'rabbit']
alphabets = []
for each_word in words:
    for x in each_word:
        if x not in alphabets:
            alphabets.append(x)
print(alphabets)
```

Now how should i convert this to list comprehension with the if statement?
Right now i can accomplish this :

```
alphabets= [x for x in each_word for each_word in words]
```

which returns

```
['c', 'a', 't', 'd', 'o', 'g', 'r', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'i', 't']
```

I need this as:

```
 ['c', 'a', 't', 'd', 'o', 'g', 'r', 'b', 'i']
```

Answer (score 5):

list comprehensions are to be used carefully. They quickly get out of hand. They also aren't built to mutate state (in this case `alphabets`).

To answer your question:

```
[alphabets.append(letter) or letter for word in words for letter in word if letter not in alphabets]
```

But this is very hacky and bad. **Don't do it.**

It works because `append` returns `None`, which makes `or` return the next (or last) value. Don't even bother with it. It's **bad code**.

---

You could do:

```
from itertools import chain

alphabets = set(chain.from_iterable(words))
```

Instead.